# SQL, Adding An Image Field/Colour Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ironspeed

Currently I have a CASE statement which applies either;

BLACK, RED, YELLOW, GREEN

As **text** to various records in the table based on some criteria.

However I was wondering if there was a way to actually colour the fields instead(Or apply an image)?

After a quick search, there doesn't seem to be much documentation on it and I was unsure where to begin.

**EDIT**

Apologies, my UI is through Iron-Speed, should I be seeking to format it from there instead?

However the criteria is specified server side.

Comment: why are you applying this on the server side and not from your application?

Comment: Colour the fields where? What application are you using to display the results?

Comment: Some code would be useful, as I'm struggling to guess how you are doing what and where and with what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to perform conditional formatting when viewing data using SQL Server Management Studio.

You could import your data into Excel (or similar) and colour it there.